# Parse output from a process that updates a single console line

Tags: c#, .net, process, console

Greetings stackoverflow members,

in a BackgroundWorker of a WPF Frontend i run [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) (open source console sound processing tool) in a `System.Diagnostics.Process`. In that same way i use several other command line tools and parse their output to poulate progress bars in my frontend.

This works fine for the other tools but not for Sox since instead of spamming new lines for each progress step, it updates a single line on the console by only using carriage returns (\r) and no line feeds (\n). I tried both asynchronous and synchronous reads on `process.StandardError`.

Using async `process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => FadeAudioOutputHandler(clip, args);` in combination with `process.BeginErrorReadLine();` doesn't produce any individual status updates because for some reason the carriage returns do not trigger ReadLine, even though the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) suggest that it should. The output is spit out in one chunk when the process finishes.

I then tried the following code for synchronous char by char reads on the stream:

```
char[] c;
var line = new StringBuilder();
while (process.StandardError.Peek() > -1)
{
    c = new char[1];
    process.StandardError.Read(c, 0, c.Length);
    if (c[0] == '\r')
    {
        var percentage = 0;
        var regex = new Regex(@"%\s([^\s]+)");
        var match = regex.Match(line.ToString());
        if (match.Success)
        {
            myProgressObject.ProgressType = ProgressType.FadingAudio
            //... some calculations omitted for brevity
            percentage = (int) Math.Round(result);
        }
        else
        {
            myProgressObject.ProgressType = ProgressType.UndefinedStep;
        }
        _backGroundWorker.ReportProgress(percentage, myProgressObject);
        line.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        line.Append(c[0]);
    }
}
```

The above code does not seem to read the stream in realtime but will stall output for a while. Then it spams a small chunk and finally deadlocks half-way through the process.

Any hints towards the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE with (sloppy?) solution:**

This drove me crazy because nothing i tried on the C# side of things seemed to have any effect on the results. My original implementation, before changing it 15 times and introducing new dependencies, was fine.

The problem is with sox and RedirectStandardError alone. I discovered that after grabbing the sox source code and building my own version. First i removed all output of sox entirely except for the stuff i was really interested in and then changing the output to full lines followed by a newline `\n` . I assumed that this would fix my issues. Well, it didn't. I do not know enough c++ to actually find out why, but they seem to have tempered with how stdio writes to that stream, how it's buffered or do it in such a special way that the streamreader on the c# side is not flushed until the default 4096 byte buffer is full. I confirmed that by padding each line to at least 4096 byte. So in conclusion all i had to do was to manually flush stderr in sox.c after each `fprintf(stderr, ...)` call in `display_status(...)`:

```
fflush(stderr);
```

Though, I'm not sure this is anywhere close to an elegant solution.

Thanks to Erik Dietrich for his answer which made me look at this from a different angle.

Comment: Your info about sox got me curious, so I did a little research.  It might be something of a long shot, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setvbuf has interesting possibilities.  It looks like you can force the buffering setting by file handle rather than by process.  This might let you 'override' the default behavior of sox so that you could leave its source alone and not be doomed to a manual update every time they update their stuff.  There may be a managed C# equivalent, or you could just write an invoke a tiny C utility.

Answer (score 9):

The situation you describe is a known problem - for a solution including source code see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ReadProcessStdoutStderr.aspx

It solves both problems (deadlock and the problem with `\n`)...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried with the ProcessIoManager from your link with the same results. Output hangs at start and then output is spit out in chunks, in lengthy tasks each chunk has a 5 second delay in between. Same happens if i use the sample gui from your link in combination with sox. There seems to be an issue with RedirectStandardError and sox output. Running sox on the command line does not show these symptoms.

Comment: The 5 second delay was the time the streamreader buffer took to fill up, please see my updated question if interested.

Comment: thanks for the update... the way you describe it it is implementation dependent, so I don't see an option other than changing SOX since there is the implementation leading to this behaviour and nothing on the reveiving side can change that...

Answer (score 2):

I've had to deal with a similar issue with a bespoke build tool in visual studio. I found that using a regex and doing the parsing in the same thread as the reading is a problem and the output processing grinds to a halt. I ended up with a standard consumer producer solution where you read lines from the output and stick them onto a Queue. Then have the queue be dequeued and processed on some other thread. I can't offer source code but this site has some fantastic resources: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx

Comment: That didn't seem to be an issue, even after commenting out the interval check for status updates resulting in several thousand lines per minute the regex part did not cause any problems.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little kludgy, but perhaps you could pipe the output of the uncooperative process to a process that does nothing but process input by characters, insert line feeds, and write to to standard out...  So, in terms of (very) pseudo-code:

```
StartProcess("sox | littleguythatIwrote")
ReadStandardOutTheWayYouAleadyAre()
```

Could be that just moves the goalposts (I'm a lot more familiar with std in/out/err in the NIX world), but it's a different way to look at the problem, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for making me check the sox side of things. See my updated question for what i came up with if you're interested.

Comment: Hmm... interesting.  I wonder if you could flush standard error on behalf of another process somehow (seems unlikely, but who knows?).  The only way I could think of would be to somehow trick sox into thinking that it's interacting with the user.  If memory serves, C libraries for STD I/O behave differently if they think they're being invoked directly by a user.  But then again, that memory is C on Linux, so take it with a grain of salt.